# improve lucene.net analyzer

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, stemming, snowballanalyzer

I'm using lucene.net and the snowball analyzer in a asp.net application.

With a specific language I'm using I have the following issue:
For two specific words with different meanings after they are stemmed the result is the same, therefore a search for any of them will produce results for both things.

How can I teach the analyzer either not to stem this two words or to, although stemming them, know that they have different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I am working from memory here but as I recall in one of the constructors you can pass an array of stopwords, which will stop the passed in words from being stemmed.

Comment: As far as I understand it, stop words are ignored during search. That's not what I want. I want to be able to search for these two words. What I'm missing is the analyzer ability to differentiate between them because after stemming they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

With Lucene 4.0, `EnglishAnalyzer` now has this ability, since it has a [constructor which takes a `stemExclusionSet`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html#EnglishAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet%29)

Of course, Lucene.Net isn't up to Lucene 4 yet, so fat lot of good that does.

However, EnglishAnalyzer does this by using a [`KeywordMarkerFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordMarkerFilter.html).  So you can create your own Analyzer, overriding the tokenStream method, and adding into the chain a `KeywordMarkerFilter` just before the `SnowballFilter`.

Something like:

```
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
    result = new StandardFilter(result);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    if (stopSet != null)
        result = new StopFilter(result, stopSet);
    result = new KeywordMarkerFilter(result, stemExclusionSet);
    result = new SnowballFilter(result, name);
    return result;
}
```

You'll need to construct your own `stemExclusionSet` (see [CharArraySet](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/CharArraySet.html)).